# Give all child elements classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to give child elements a class per group. So each groups children will have the same class for each group, and each element should have a different class.

This is what i got so far:

```
var $span = $("tr.keep td");
$span.attr('id', function (index) {
return 'td' + index;
});
```

The problem is that I have multiple groups of the same parent - this script runs trough all of them instead repeating the class for each group. How do I ad something like .each on this script, or is it a better way?

HTML:

```
  <tr class="keep">
   <tr class="test">
    <td rowspan="2"><a href="/"><img src="/" alt=""></a></td>
    <td colspan="3"><a href="/">text</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="test">
    <td>MF216N/A</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td class="outofstock">0</td>
    <td>1&nbsp;054,24SEK</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="actionbutton" value="Köp" onclick="buy(this, 65360, null, null,null, '/ajax/buy')"></td>
   </tr>
 </tr>


  <tr class="keep">
   <tr class="test">
    <td rowspan="2"><a href="/"><img src="/" alt=""></a></td>
    <td colspan="3"><a href="/">text</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="test">
    <td>MF216N/A</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td class="outofstock">0</td>
    <td>1&nbsp;054,24SEK</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="actionbutton" value="Köp" onclick="buy(this, 65360, null, null,null, '/ajax/buy')"></td>
   </tr>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Keep a `global-variable` and add `index` in `global`

Comment: You should use `class` not `id`. `id` is unique on each element.

Comment: You *cannot* have duplicate ID in the same document. It's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tr.test` selector to select all the `tr` elements having class as `.test`. Iterate this selected elements using `.each` and find `td` elements which are children of `selected-tr` elements. Loop through `td` elements and and add class using `.addClass` considering the index.

**Note:** `tr` elements can not have `tr` as its children. That will be `invalid-markup`

```js
var $span = $("tr.test");
$span.each(function(i, elem) {
  $(elem).find('td').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass(function() {
      return 'td_' + (index + 1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.td_1 {
  background: yellow;
}
.td_2 {
  background: green;
}
.td_3 {
  background: pink;
}
.td_4 {
  background: orange;
}
.td_5 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="keep">
    <td rowspan="2">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="/" alt="">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3"><a href="/">text</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="test">
    <td>MF216N/A</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td class="outofstock">0</td>
    <td>1&nbsp;054,24SEK</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="actionbutton" value="Köp" onclick="buy(this, 65360, null, null,null, '/ajax/buy')">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="keep">
    <td rowspan="2">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="/" alt="">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3"><a href="/">text</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="test">
    <td>MF216N/A</td>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td class="outofstock">0</td>
    <td>1&nbsp;054,24SEK</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="actionbutton" value="Köp" onclick="buy(this, 65360, null, null,null, '/ajax/buy')">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8xoccz0u/1/)

Comment: this is doing the same as my script - it keeps running the uniqe id until the last element - i need the id to repeat its self for the next group. So first group would have id 1,2,3,4 etc, and next group will also have 1,2,3,4. This will go as 1,2,3,4 and then 5,6,7,8. I was a bit unclear - updated mu question.

Comment: Then class - if thats possible. I want the same td elements in each grouo to have the same identifier for styling purposes.

Comment: You can have static classes..  Why do you need them to be dynamic ?

Comment: I guess Im really unclear - sorry. I just need each TD in each group to have different identifier - and then repeat that in the next group with same identifier for the matching elements since they are the same.

Comment: And for styling purpose, go with the classes.. Another hint could be using `nth-child`..

Comment: Yeah - but it doesn't have to be an id - I changed my original question. All I need is to be able to style each matching element in each group independently from the other TD elements. If its possible to give them classes then that works.

Comment: Would prefer not to use nth-child though

Comment: Any reason for that ?

Comment: Mainly because of win 8 - which is widely used by our customerbase unfortunaly.

Comment: How could you relate this with `win-8` ?

Comment: Because the compatibility with nth-child isn't good enough for my needs basically. There are work arounds - but i simply dont want to go that route . I rather assing classes to the TD elements.

Comment: "partial support" I have already tried this and found it not working good enough for my needs.

Comment: How do you want your class names to be like ?

Comment: Yes! thats perfect. I can accept the answer if you update it :)

Answer (score 0):

user can use parent element index for add unique id for each child

```
$("tr.keep").each(function (parentIndex) {
$(this).find('td').each(function (childIndex) {
    $(this).attr('id', parentIndex + '' + childIndex)
   })
});
```

Comment: Also please, know the difference between `this` and `$(this)`

Comment: This will return a bunch of elements sharing the same ID

Comment: @ateferov this is doing the same as my script - it keeps running the uniqe id until the last element - i need the id to repeat its self for the next group. So first group would have id 1,2,3,4 etc, and next group will also have 1,2,3,4. This will go as 1,2,3,4 and then 5,6,7,8. I was a bit unclear - updated mu question.

Comment: @JerrySvensson: you can try $(this).addClass(childIndex)

Comment: @Neophyte This doesn't seems to work - could you give me an example of how the script should look? I don´t get any errors, but it wont apply any classes.